# IIS ignoring rewrite rules

Tags: iis, web-config, url-rewriting

I have the following web.config. I think there is nothing wrong with my it, but I can't get it to rewrite to index. I also tried url="index.php" without leading /

Is there anything wrong with my web.config? Or is there anything else that can be wrong (like IIS settings) - if so, is it possible to check without having access to server (other than FTP to page)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
            <sectionGroup name="rewrite">
                <section name="rewriteMaps" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
                <section name="rules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="NWCMS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make index.php default document when open an URL without filename. Try this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
       <system.webServer>
          <defaultDocument enabled="true">
             <files>                      
                <add value="index.php"/> 
             </files>
          </defaultDocument>
          <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
       </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```